# Weird mySQL error when adding to a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I've used this exact code with a slight modification of the values in another script and it worked just fine, but this time it's giving me errors. This is the line:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (name, email, telephone, companyname, postcode, message, date) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $userEmail . "', '" . $telephone . "', '" . $companyName . "', '" . $message . "', '" . $date . "'") or die (mysql_error());
```

I've tried echo-ing out all of the variables with this:

```
<p>Name: <?php echo $name; ?>, <br />Email: <?php echo $userEmail; ?>, <br />Telephone: <?php echo $telephone; ?>, <br />Company name: <?php echo $companyName; ?>, <br />Message: <?php echo $message; ?>, <br />Date: <?php echo $date; ?>, <br /></p>
```

Which displays them all fine when the form is submitted. However, when I try to add them to a database it flips out and says this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I'm assuming I'm either missing something simple, I've made a typo somewhere (although I've re-typed it to double check it wasn't that).

Here's the way my database is set-up:

[image: database set-up]
Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

I added the missing `)` to the query and that got rid of the first error, but now I'm getting this error when I submit it:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

---

**FIXED**

I was missing the `$postcode` variable. Doh!

Comment: Good error description. Very nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `)` at the end of you query, for the `VALUES()`.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (name, email, telephone, companyname, postcode, message, date) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $userEmail . "', '" . $telephone . "', '" . $companyName . "', '" . $message . "', '" . $date . "')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: I updated my first post. I added the `)` symbol but I'm getting a new error I've not encountered before

Comment: @Bobby I was just about to update the post to say I'd fixed it. You're right, that's what was missing. Thanks for the reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

You declare one more field than give in VALUES. This might be the thing with column count.